# How can we improve the performance of PowerBI reading from Azure Databricks lakehouse delta tables

Tags: powerbi, databricks, azure-databricks, powerbi-desktop, delta-lake

We are loading our data to delta tables in Azure Databricks stored over ADLS Gen2

We are using Data Engineering workspace in databricks and a standard DS3V2 cluster to read data into the PowerBI ( both in import and DirectQuery mode)

Our batch and streaming data write to same table and this results in lot of files created in the delta table location

PowerBI DirectQuery reads are very slow and we want to improve the refresh times.

We looked at this new blog (
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure-blog/power-up-your-bi-with-microsoft-power-bi-and-lakehouse-in-azure/ba-p/3816771

) which suggests using SQL Warehouse but we already have synapse in our design for analytical workloads and thus Databricks SQL warehouse seems redundant at this moment

Has anyone encountered such similar issues with PowerBi reading from the lakehouse and how did you improve the performance ?

---

EDIT 1: Databricks connection info to be used in PowerBI connector for databricks

[image]

Comment: How are you reading delta tables from PowerBI? Last I checked there are no Microsoft-sanctioned connectors for delta tables in PowerBI. There's an M library, but that doesn't support all features of delta tables, so you need to have a bridge between delta lake and PowerBI i.e. databricks schema or synapse sql database.

Comment: We are using Azure Databricks connector in provided in the PowerBI desktop/service which connects to Databricks using AAD user id and JDBC connection like the one shown in the EDIT 1  above

Comment: I think you're using an ideal set of technologies, and unless a connector for reading the delta tables directly from data lake is released, what you're doing is the best course of action.